Comedy movie about a guy who is trying to get enough money to pay his cab fare
I would have seen this movie on TV in the late 1960s or early 1970s I think.  The movie might have been made in the 1950s.  I don't recall whether or not it was in color.  (Edit: It is not "After Hours" -- it's much older)
A young man takes a ride in a taxicab driven by someone who I believe is a friend of his.  Upon reaching his destination he discovers he doesn't have enough money to pay the fare.  His friend the driver can't cover for him and so they drive someplace else where he can get the balance.  However the meter continues to run and so while he is able to get more money, it is not enough to cover the new increased fare.  This scenario is repeated multiple times, with increasingly desperate measures being taken.
I have a pretty clear memory of one sequence where they stop at a blood bank.  Our hero goes in and sells a jar of blood, takes the money, and goes directly from the exit to the entrance and does it again.  After 3 or 4 cycles through, he staggers to the payment area carrying a bottle* only partially full, grabs a random handful of cash, and barely makes it back to the cab.

*I'm definitely certain it was a glass bottle; which dates the scene as before blood donations went into plastic bags.

https://irememberthismovie.com/taxi-passenger-cant-pay-ever-increasing-fare/

Could this be After Hours (1985)?

In a Manhattan cafe, word processor Paul Hackett (Griffin Dunne) meets
and talks literature with Marcy (Rosanna Arquette). Later that night,
Paul takes a cab to Marcy's downtown apartment. His $20 bill flying
out the window during the ride portends the unexpected night he has.
He cannot pay for the ride and finds himself in a series of awkward,
surreal and life-threatening situations with a colorful cast of
characters. He spends the rest of the night trying to return uptown.





It's very late, and the synopsis isn't a fab match, but I can see this being the victim of poor memory

It's not After Hours, although that one looks interesting too.  Edited.
